# ¿Cómo paso como parametro un arreglo bidimensional en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Estoy desarrollando un programa con canvas HTML5 Y JavaScript donde en una clase defino un componente gráfico y en otra clase dibujo haciendo llamados a ese componente. Hasta aquí todo bien, solo que ahora me han pedido que separe el dibujo en dos funciones, en una de ellas llene los arreglos con los elementos gráficos y en la otra recorra el arreglo y los pinte. El detalle es que en la primer función lleno un arreglo bidimensional y no sé como pasárselo a otra función como parámetro (soy novato en JavaScript).

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Básicamente tengo una clase GraphicComponent a la cual le paso los parametros (x,y,width,heigth y algunos textos) y es a la que hago llamados.

```
//arreglo que contendrá todas los elementos
var parrilla = new Array(4);

//arreglos que alojaran los elementos gráficos de los trimestres
var lote1  = new Array(13);
var lote2  = new Array(13);
var lote3  = new Array(13);
var lote4  = new Array(13);

this.almacen = function(ctx)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < lote4.length; i++)
    {
        trimLote4[i]=new GraphicComponent(xLote4, yLote4+(separacion)*(i+1), width, height, textLote4[i], clavesLote4[i], creditosLote4[i]);
    }
    ....

    for (var i = 0; i < lote1.length; i++)
    {
        ...
    }

    parrilla[0] = lote1;
    parrilla[1] = lote2;
    parrilla[2] = lote3;
    parrilla[3] = lote4;
};

this.pinta = function(gridUEAs)
{
    for(var i=0; i < parrilla.length;i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<parrilla[i].length;j++)
        {
            parrilla[i][j].draw(ctx);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Por favor, añade algo de codigo que estes probando para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: He añadido un poco de código, espero se entienda.

Comment: masomenos, entonces  `parrilla` tiene que acabar siendo `gridUEAs` ?

Comment: Así es, perdón por el error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

La forma de pasar una argumento a una función es   `miFuncion(parametro)` y en el caso de una función anónima `function (parametro){...}`

## Explicación

### Cómo pasar un argumento a una función

En JavaScript las variables pueden hacer referencia a cualquier valor, ya sea uno primitivo como un número o una cadena de texto (string) o un objeto, incluyendo una matriz (array) tanto unidimensional como multidimensional.

Para pasar un parámetro a una función, basta con poner el valor o la variable dentro de los paréntesis de la llamada a la función.

Si la función se llama miFuncion, la forma de llamarla sin parámetros es miFuncion() y con parámetros miFuncion(parametro).

### Ejemplos

#### Función con nombre

```js
// Imprime en la consola el valor del parámetro
function miFuncion(parametro) {
  console.info(parametro);
}

// Una cadena como parámetro
miFuncion('¡Hola mundo!');

// Una matriz multidimensional como parámetro
miFuncion([
  ['Hola'],
  ['mundo']
]);

// Una variable que hace referencia a un matriz multidimensional, y esta como parámetro
var miVariable = [
  ['Adiós'],
  ['mundo']
];

miFuncion(miVariable);
```

### E Función anónima

```js
// Imprime en la consola el valor del parámetro
// Se asigna una función anónima a una variable para poder llamarla.
var funcionAnonima = function (parametro) {
  console.info(parametro);
}

// Una cadena como parámetro
funcionAnonima('¡Hola mundo!');

// Una matriz multidimensional como parámetro
funcionAnonima([
  ['Hola'],
  ['mundo']
]);

// Una variable que hace referencia a un matriz multidimensional, y esta como parámetro
var miVariable = [
  ['Adiós'],
  ['mundo']
];

funcionAnonima(miVariable);
```

## Referencias

- [Introudcción Guía de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introducci%C3%B3n)
- [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/function)

Comment: Después de un rato de estar a "prueba y error" me di cuenta que con solo hacer referencia al objeto, de acuerdo a las propiedades que aplique en la función será el objeto que estoy usando.

En mi caso la función que buscaba hacer quedó de la siguiente manera:

    this.dibujar = function(gridUEAs){
        for(var i = 0; i < gridUEAs.length; i++){

            for(var j = 0;j < gridUEAs[0].length; j++){

                if(gridUEAs[i][j] != null){
                    
                    gridUEAs[i][j].draw(ctx);
                }
            }
        }
    };